# Net 6 webapi OData v4 Pagination, missing total count and next page link

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, odata, webapi

I have .net 6 webapi including Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData 8.0.10.
In my startup.cs I have:

```
services.AddControllers()
.AddOData(options =>
 {
     options.Filter().Select().OrderBy().Count().SetMaxTop(serviceSettings.MaxPageSize).SkipToken().AddRouteComponents("api", GetEdmModel());
 });
```

AddRouteComponents is this necessary?

```
private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
    {
        ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<ModuleView>("Module").EntityType.HasKey(o => o.Id);
        return builder.GetEdmModel();
    }
```

ModuleView is materialized MSSqlServer View.

Next I have my controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ModuleController : ODataController
```

Where I have endpoint:

```
[EnableQuery]
[HttpGet("[action]")]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public async Task<ActionResult<IQueryable<ModuleView>>> GetModuleFilter()
{
    return Ok(_moduleViewRepository.GetModuleViewData());
    //var tResult = _moduleViewRepository.GetModuleViewData();
            //return Ok(new PageResult<ModuleView>(tResult, Request.ODataFeature().NextLink, Request.ODataFeature().TotalCount));
}
```

_moduleViewRepository.GetModuleViewData() return DbSet AsQueryable()

Now when I run in browser:

```
https://localhost:44355/api/Module/GetModuleFilter
```

I have all rows in json like:
[
{
"Id": 1,
},
{
"Id": 2,
}
]

I don't see "@odata.context", total count, next page link.

$select, $skip, $top works. But I can't run pagination... I cant return all rows count number and next link. If i try $count=true I have the same result with  all object. When I try add [EnableQuery(PageSize=5)] api return 5 rows.
Whats wrong?

I would like to set PageSize from front-end, but front-end need to now how many rows is in dbset.

I cant understand how work $skiptoken and how can I use it.

Someone can help?

I found that the Odata context does not work when using a changed endpoint path like:

```
[HttpGet("api/[controller]/[action]")]
```

But I dont know how to fix it, what if I want to add more than one odata endpoint?